# Why does overloading the post increment operator in C++ call the constructor twice?

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-overloading, post-increment

I was playing with overloading different operators and added print statements to watch what was happening. When I overloaded the post increment operator, I saw that the constructor was being called twice, but I don't understand why.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ParentClass {
    public:
    ParentClass() {
        cout << "In ParentClass!" << endl;
    }
};

class ChildClass : public ParentClass {
    public:
        int value;
        ChildClass() { }
        ChildClass(int a)
        : value(a) {  
            cout << "In ChildClass!" << endl;
        }

        int getValue() { return value; } 

        ChildClass operator++( int ) {
            cout << "DEBUG 30\n";
            this->value++;
            return this->value; 
        }
};

int main() {
    cout << "DEBUG 10\n";
    ChildClass child(0);
    cout << "value initial     = " << child.getValue() << endl;
    cout << "DEBUG 20\n";
    child++;
    cout << "DEBUG 40\n";
    cout << "value incremented = " << child.getValue() << endl;
}
```

The output after running this code is:

```
DEBUG 10
In ParentClass!
In ChildClass!
value initial     = 0
DEBUG 20
DEBUG 30
In ParentClass!
In ChildClass!
DEBUG 40
value incremented = 1
```

Comment: Note that the code overloads the **post**-increment operator but implements a **pre**-increment.

Comment: @PeteBecker Maybe I'm missing something. I thought that adding the parameter 'int' in operator++(int) implements post incrementation?

Comment: The code returns the incremented value. That’s what pre-increment does. Post-increment should return the original value.

Comment: @PeteBecker You are correct sir! I was thinking that the incremented value had to be returned, but now I realize that it only has to be incremented to simulate the behavior of integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement

```
  return this->value;
```

Says return `int`

But the method prototype is

```
 ChildClass operator++( int )
```

So the compiler thinks, got an `int` need a `ChildClass` - Lets construct one from the `int`. Hence the output

Comment: I was following an example for binary operators where a new type with the result is returned.  I removed the return statement, and indeed the constructor is called but once now. And also changing the return type to int works. Thanks!

Comment: @yamex5 , having  `ChildClass`'s  `++` return `int` is a really nasty surprise for anyone expecting the usual behaviour of `operator++`. See [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading) for an extensive write-up on operator overloading.

Comment: @user4581301 - It is not returning an `int`. See the prototype and my explaination

Comment: I know that. I was warning yamex that the course of action they outlined at the end of their comment was a bad idea.